# Select one number at a time between 0 & 10 billion in random order

Tags: algorithm, search, memory-management, random

#### Problem

I have a need to pick one unique random number at a time between 0 and 10,000,000,000 and do it till all numbers are selected. Essentially the behavior I need is a pre-built stack/queue with 10 billion numbers in random order, with no ability to push new items into it.

#### Not so good ways to solve:

There's no shortage of inefficient ways in my brain. Such as,

- persist generated numbers and check newly generated random number is already used, at some point this gets us into indefinite wait before a usable number is produced.
- Persist all possible numbers in a table and pop a random row and maintain new row count for next pick etc. Not sure if this is good or bad.

#### Questions:

1. Are there other deterministic ways besides storing all possible combinations and using random?

   - Like maintaining windows of available numbers and randomly select a window first and randomly select a number within that window etc. eg: like [this](https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/spuli-publicly-shared-s3/Select-Random-From-Pool.html)
2. If not, what is the best type to store numbers in reasonably small amount of space?

   - 50+% of numbers wont fit in a 32 bit (int), 64 bit (long) is waste. Cos largest number fits in 34 bits, wasting 30 bits per number (>37GB total).

If this problem hasn't been solved already.

3. What is a good data structure for storing & picking a random spot and quickly adjust the structure for next pick to be fast?

***Sorry for the ambiguity. The largest selectable number is 9,999,999,999 and smallest selectable is 1.

Comment: How perfect does the randomness have to be? Do you need all ten-billion-factorial permutations to be equally likely?

Comment: You may want to look into a [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Comment: Do you want the numbers between 1 and 10 billion or 0 and 10 billion? Title says one thing, question says another.

Comment: You need lg((10^10)!) bits to store all possible permutations of 10b numbers, so... 4,584,883,940 bits -> 547MB. So, for full randomness, that's your _minimum_ space for #2.

Comment: @ruakh the randomness doesn't have to be completely perfect.

Comment: @samgak, it's 0 & 10 bil.  Meaning smallest number I can select is 1, largest number I can select is 9,999,999,999

Comment: @MooingDuck You could write the data to a file vs RAM or a combination of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask: "Are there other deterministic ways besides storing all possible combinations and using random?"

Yes there is: Encryption.  Encryption with a given key guarantees a unique result for unique inputs since it is reversible.  Each key defines a one-to-one permutation of the possible inputs.  You need an encryption of inputs in the range [1..10e9].  To deal with something that big you need 34 bit numbers, which go up to 17,179,869,183.

There is no standard 34 bit encryption.  Depending on how much security you need, and how fast you need the numbers, you can either write your own simple, fast, insecure four-round [Feistel Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) or else for something slower and more secure use [Hasty Pudding cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher) in 34 bit mode.

With either solution, if the first encryption gives a result outside the range, just encrypt the result again until the new result is within the range you want.  The one-to-one property ensures that the final result of the chain of encryptions will be unique.

To generate a sequence of unique random-seeming numbers just encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... in order with the same key.  Encryption guarantees that the results will be unique for that key.  If you record how far you have got, then you can generate more unique numbers later, up to your 10 billion limit.

Comment: I don't see how this helps

Comment: Encrypt 0 to get a 'random' number.  Encrypt 1 to get a guaranteed different 'random' number.  Encrypt 3 to get a third guaranteed different 'random' number.  Repeat until all possible numbers are picked, or stop when you have got enough.  you can always restart with encrypting the next number in sequence.  No need to store all the numbers, just store the key and the lowest and highest in the range you've used.  You can always recalculate whenever needed.

Comment: I was really surprised to see somebody mention Hasty Pudding Cipher on Stack Overflow!  Then I see it is rossum!  Okay, you are one of the few that would know it!  :-)

Comment: +1. Note that with this approach, not all ten-billion-factorial permutations are actually possible (since there are nowhere near ten-billion-factorial distinct possible encryption keys); but since the OP comments above that "the randomness doesn't have to be completely perfect", it seems very likely that that's fine.

Comment: I don't know of any non-custom encryption that can take a number between 0-10b and produce a guaranteed different number 0-10b. Every standard encryption will give you numbers bigger than 10b. And if you use modulo, you lose the guaranteed different. In which case numbers repeat, and have differing likelihoods.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't disagree, but doesn't this answer already provide a solution for that?

Comment: @ruakh: Yes, given a single key you only get one possible permutation.  Since the question needs guaranteed non-repeating output ("unique") then one single permutation (= key) is a required element of the solution.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Repeated encryption will uniquely produce a number in the required range.  It will take longer if you use too large a block size, hence my advice to use Hasty Pudding or a 34-bit Feistel cipher.

Comment: Though LCG is a more perfect solution, I ended up using this solution. 
Marking this as answer cos little bit of predictability and occasional errors are bearable in my particular situation.

Comment: @rossum: I'm extremely skeptical of claims of an encryption that would uniquely produce a number _in the required range_, but I don't know enough about details about those encryption to claim for certain.

Comment: Encryption is uniquely reversible, otherwise we could not reliably decrypt the cyphertext.  Since it is uniquely reversible, then running forwards or backwards through a series of repeated encryptions of a block is also unique.  Hasty Pudding cipher uses this property to allow for non-standard ranges, other than powers of 2.  The same logic applies to any block cipher.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by AChampion in the comments, you could use a [Linear Congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Your modulo (m) value will be 10 billion. In order to get a full period (all values in the range appear before the series repeats) you need to choose the a and c constants to satisfy certain criteria. m and c need to be relatively prime and a - 1 needs to be divisible by the prime factors of m (which are just 2 and 5) and also by 4 (since 10 billion is divisible by 4).

If you just come up with a single set of constants, you will only have one possible series and the numbers will always occur in the same order. However you can easily randomly generate constants that satisfy the criteria. To test for relative primality of c and m, just test if c is divisible by 2 and 5, since these are the only prime factors of m (see first condition of coprimality test [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers))

Simple sketch in Python:

```
import random

m = 10000000000
a = 0
c = 0
r = 0

def setupLCG():
    global a, c, r
    # choose value of c that is 0 < c < m and relatively prime to m
    c = 5
    while ((c % 5 == 0) or (c % 2 == 0)):
        c = random.randint(1, m - 1)
    # choose value of a that is 0 < a <= m and a - 1 is divisible by
    # prime factors of m, and 4
    a = 4
    while ((((a - 1) % 4) != 0) or (((a - 1) % 5) != 0)):
        a = random.randint(1, m)
    r = random.randint(0, m - 1)

def rand():
    global m, a, c, r
    r = (a*r + c) % m
    return r

random.seed()
setupLCG()
for i in range(1000):    
    print rand() + 1
```

This approach won't give the full possibility of 10000000000! possible combinations, but it will still be on the order of 10<sup>19</sup>, which is quite a lot. It does have a few other issues (e.g. alternates even and odd values). You could mix it up a bit by having a small pool of numbers, adding a number from the sequence to it each time and randomly drawing one out.

Comment: @pjs. I was wondering about that. The question says 0-10 billion, but the title says 1-10 billion. I've assumed the latter for now because OP also said they want 10 billion numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I upvoted the comment that pointed out the ambiguity.  Hopefully OP will respond.

Comment: Note: prime factors of `10000000001` are `11^2 * 23 * 4093 * 8779`

Comment: If the range is 1 to 9999999999 inclusive then you can just discard 10 billion when you come across it. Or else adapt the algorithm for the prime factors of 9999999999. However the first option is easier because there will be many more valid values of a.

Comment: Thank you for the help with implementation, it helped me understand the concept easier than reading the literature.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what rossum has suggested, you can use [invertible integer hash function](https://gist.github.com/lh3/974ced188be2f90422cc), which uniquely maps an integer in [0,2^k) to another integer in the same range. For your particular problem, you choose k=34 (2^34=16 billion) and reject any number above 10 billion. Here is a complete implementation:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t hash_64(uint64_t key, uint64_t mask)
{
    key = (~key + (key << 21)) & mask; // key = (key << 21) - key - 1;
    key = key ^ key >> 24;
    key = ((key + (key << 3)) + (key << 8)) & mask; // key * 265
    key = key ^ key >> 14;
    key = ((key + (key << 2)) + (key << 4)) & mask; // key * 21
    key = key ^ key >> 28;
    key = (key + (key << 31)) & mask;
    return key;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t i, shift, mask, max = 10000ULL;
    char *dummy;
    if (argc > 1) max = strtol(argv[1], &dummy, 10);
    for (shift = 0; 1ULL<<shift <= max; ++shift) {}
    mask = (1ULL<<shift) - 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= mask; ++i) {
        uint64_t x = hash_64(i, mask);
        x = hash_64(x, mask);
        x = hash_64(x, mask); // apply multiple times to increase randomness
        if (x > max || x == 0) continue;
        printf("%llu\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This should give you number [0,10000000000] in random order.

Comment: Thank you for saving me time in implementing the solution. Appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

For the range `1-999,999,999,999` is equivalent `0-999,999,999,998` (just add `1`). Given the definition of [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) then you can implement this:

```
import functools as ft
import itertools as it
import operator as op
from sympy import primefactors, nextprime

def LCG(m, seed=0):
    factors = set(primefactors(m))
    a = ft.reduce(op.mul, factors)+1
    assert(m%4 != 0 or (m%4 == 0 and (a-1)%m == 0))
    c = nextprime(max(factors)+1)
    assert(c < m)
    x = seed
    while True:
        x = (a * x + c) % m
        yield x

# Check the first 10,000,000 for duplicates
>>> x = list(it.islice(LCG(999999999999), 10000000))
>>> len(x) == len(set(x))
True
# Last 10 numbers
>>> x[-10:]
[99069910838, 876847698522, 765736597318, 99069940559, 210181061577,
 432403293706, 99069970280, 543514424631, 99069990094, 99070000001]
```

I've taken a couple of shortcuts for the context of this question as the `assert`s should be replaced with handling code, currently it would just fail if those `assert`s were `False`

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to LCG. Though this is more perfect, I ended up using rossum's solution.  I greatly appreciate the introduction to this new (to me) concept.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any truly random methods of picking the numbers without storing a list of the numbers already picked.   You could do some sort of linear hashing algorithm, and then pass the numbers 0 to n through it (repeating when your hash returns a value above 10000000000), but this wouldn't be truly random.

If you are to store the numbers, you might consider doing it via a bitmask.   To pick quickly in the bitmask, you would likely keep a tree, where each leaf would represent the number of free bits in the corresponding 32 bytes, the branches above that would list the number of free bits in the corresponding 2K entries, and so forth.  You then have O(log(n)) time to find your next entry, and O(log(n)) time to claim a bit (as you have to update the tree).   It would require something to the order of 2n bits to store as well.

Answer (score 0):

If predictability is not a concern, you can generate quickly using XOR operations. Suppose you want to generate a random sequence of unique numbers with n bits (34 in your case):

1- take a seed number on n bits. This number, `K`, can be considered as a seed that you can change each time you run a new experiment.

2- Use a counter from 0 upward

3- Each time XOR the counter with `K` :  `next = counter xor K; counter++;`

To limit the range to 10 Billion, which is not a power of two, you will need to do rejection.

The obvious drawback is predictability. In step 3, you can do a prior transposition on the bytes of the counter, for example inverse the order of the bytes (like when you transform from little-endian to big endian). This would yield some improvement concerning the predictability of the next number.

Finally I have to admit that this answer can be considered as a particular implementation of encryption which was mentioned in the answer of @rossum, but it's more specific and probably fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need to store all the numbers.

If you want a perfect set of the numbers from 1 to 10B each exactly once, there are two options that I see: as hinted at by the others, use a 34-bit LCG or Galois LFSR or XOR-shift that generates a sequence of numbers from 1 to 17B or so, then throw out the ones over 10B. I am not aware of any specifically 34-bit functions for this, but I'm sure someone is.

Option 2, if you can spare 1.25 GB of memory, is to create a bitmap that stores only the information that a certain number has been chosen, then use Floyd's Algorithm to get the numbers, which would be fast and give you much better quality numbers (in fact, it would work just fine with hardware RNGs).

Option 3, if you can live with a rare but occasional mistake (duplicate or never-selected number), replace the bitmap with a Bloom filter and save memory.

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly slow but it should work. Completely random

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Random random = new Random();
        static void Main()
        {
            const long start = 1;
            const long NumData = 10000000000;
            const long RandomNess = NumData;
            var sz = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(long));
            var numBytes = NumData * sz;

            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                // create file with numbers in order
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                for (var index = start; index < NumData; index++)
                {
                    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(index);
                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, sz);
                }

                for (var iteration = 0L; iteration < RandomNess; iteration++)
                {

                    // get 2 random longs
                    var item1Index = LongRandom(0, NumData - 1, random);
                    var item2Index = LongRandom(0, NumData - 1, random);


                    // allocate room for data
                    var data1ByteArray = new byte[sz];
                    var data2ByteArray = new byte[sz];

                    // read the first value
                    stream.Seek(item1Index * sz, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    stream.Read(data1ByteArray, 0, sz);

                    // read the second value
                    stream.Seek(item2Index * sz, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    stream.Read(data2ByteArray, 0, sz);

                    var item1 = BitConverter.ToInt64(data1ByteArray, 0);
                    var item2 = BitConverter.ToInt64(data2ByteArray, 0);

                    Debug.Assert(item1 < NumData);
                    Debug.Assert(item2 < NumData);

                    // swap the values
                    stream.Seek(item1Index * sz, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    stream.Write(data2ByteArray, 0, sz);

                    stream.Seek(item2Index * sz, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    stream.Write(data1ByteArray, 0, sz);
                }

            }
            File.Delete(filePath);

            Console.WriteLine($"{numBytes}");

        }

        static long LongRandom(long min, long max, Random rand)
        {
            long result = rand.Next((int)(min >> 32), (int)(max >> 32));
            result = (result << 32);
            result = result | rand.Next((int)min, (int)max);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```